# Remove index in pandas data-frame while converting to html table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to remove index while converting pandas data-frame into html table. Prototype is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.DataFrame({'list':np.random.rand(100)})
html_table = df.to_html()
```

In html table I don't want to display index.

Comment: Can you add data sample and desired output?

Comment: Please have a look at image available in the link.

Comment: don't post a link to an image, we require raw data and your code to reproduce your df correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I think [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @jezrael sure, Editing for same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
html_table = df.to_html(index = False)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you need remove index name:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

Or:

```
df.index.name = None
```

For not display index use:

```
print (df.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: Yes that removes the index name but not 'index column' as I found(from Stack-overflow ) that it is not possible to remove index from Dataframe but column can be used as index but I need the column that can be used as index in the same level of other columns.

Comment: @arshpreet - I really dont understand - what is desired output? Do you need index name and only remove empty row? I think it is not possible.

Comment: But you can use `df.columns.name='a'` and `df.index.name = None` - it looks nice, but  after `df = df.reset_index()` get column called `index`

Comment: that means we simple can't remove index column from Pandas DataFrame and also can't make 'index column name' in same row as oher columns exist?

Comment: You need always some index in pandas dataframe. You cannot remove it, only reaasign to default `df.reset_index(drop=True)` or set to another column.

Comment: yes that is fine, I was aware of that but isn't it some kind of limit, I mean yes AFAIK index needs to be there for Pandas to keep track of columns but there should be one options either one wants to display it or not.

Comment: Then need `df.to_string(index=False)` ;)

Comment: @arshpreet - Done.